# Model Attribute Type: what is the difference between json and ref?

Tags: sails.js, sails-mongo, sails-postgresql

In the documentation regarding [built-in data types](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/validations#?builtin-data-types), it is written:

> **json**: Any JSON-serializable value, including numbers, booleans, strings, arrays, dictionaries (plain JavaScript objects), and null.
>
> **ref**: Any JavaScript value except undefined. (Should only be used when taking advantage of adapter-specific behavior.)

I can't figure out the difference between them. When to use one instead of the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ref` in conjunction with `columnType` can be used to represent native database data types, and use them, like binary data.

Check the following link for more information

https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/attributes#?columntype